# How to expand a discrete signal into a Fourier series?

Tags: fft, series, expansion

[image: I need to find coefficients in cirkle]

```
u_i(x_j,t) is an array of numbers:
let's say {      0.1 0.3 0.5 0.2 0.4;      <-- i = 1
                 0.5 0.3 0.6 0.3 0.1;      <-- i = 2
                 0.6   1   7 0.4  9;       <-- i = 3 
                                      }
each number in a row corresponds to given time 
let's take first row: 0.1 is t = 0.1 sec 
                      0.3 is t = 0.2 sec
                      0.5 is t = 0.3 sec
                      0.2 is t = 0.4 sec
                      0.4 is t = 0.5 sec
```

u_i may be represented as is given on the picture. Is it possible to find coefficients circled on the picture? a_i_n, k_n_j, omega_n, b_i_n?

Comment: it is also known that omega(n) = constant * k(1,n) and 
a(j,m)*k(j,n) = b(j,m) *k(j,n) =0

Comment: Unless I am missing something you want the Fourier transform. Don't know which language you're using, but for most prog languages there are libraries containing an FFT function, that computes those coefs for you.